# jQuery datepicker, 2 questions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

For the first question, I have the function:

```
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       onSelect: function () {
           $('#date').text($(this).val());
       },
       onChangeMonthYear: function () {
           $('#date').text($(this).val());
      }
  });
});
```

The onSelect works, but the onChangeMonthYear doesn't. Am I using it wrong?

The second question is, once I get the month change to work, how can I split up the date so I can put it into a url like "myfile.php?y=2010&m=11&d=01". I have a mainly PHP background, so exploding the string is tempting, but I'm sure theres a better way. Thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own problem with onChangeMonthYear. The way I had it is was calling onSelect each time as well as onChangeMonthYear when the month changed. I rearanged it, and it seems to work fine. The following is the end-result including both Justin's reply, and a guy that deleted his answer:

```
$(function() {
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     onChangeMonthYear: function () {
         $('#date').text("Changed Month");
     },
     onSelect: function () {
         var date = $(this).val().split("/")
         $('#date').text("Month: " + date[0] + " Day: " + date[1] + " Year: " + date[2]);
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onChangeMonthYear) for `onChangeMonthYear` the year, month, and datepicker instance are sent as parameters:

> function(year, month, inst)
>
> Allows you to define your own event when the datepicker moves to a new month and/or year. The function receives the selected year, month (1-12), and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

So try using it like this:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { ... }
});
```

---

With regard to your second question, you can use the `getDate` API method to extract the date into a date object:

```
var myDate = jQuery(myDatePicker).datepicker( 'getDate' );
```

Then you can use the [date object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date#Methods_2) to extract out the date parts. For example:

```
var url = "y=" + myDate.getFullYear() +
         "&m=" + myDate.getMonth() + 
         "&d=" + myDate.getDate();
```

Comment: Considering the code in my initial post, what would year, month, and inst be?

Comment: Presumably `year` and `month` correspond to the values the user selected, and `inst` should correspond to `this`.